# Is there option to show attributes of operations in Rational Software Architect?

Tags: uml, rational-rsa

I'm fairly new to Rational Software Architect and it annoys the hell out of me that I can't see attributes of operations (methods) in UML diagrams. If I add method called `get()` with attributes `att1` and `att2`, I'd like to see `get(In att1, In att2)` on diagram.

Is there a possibility to show this by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the class diagram background and then use the show hide compartment option. You have attributes and methods compartments which need to selected in order to be displayed graphically.

It worked pretty well last time I evaluated the Rational tools.

Comment: I'm talking about attributes of operations (aka methods) tho. So if I add method called _get()_ with attributes _att1_ and _att2_, I'd like to see _get(In att1, In att2)_ on diagram.

Comment: It also work well if I remember. I did the test. Try the class diagram contextual menu (e.g. click on the class diagram background and be sure that no element are selected at the time of the click by the mouse otherwise it would be another menu) and try preferences or filter submenu.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on a class -> "Filters" -> "Show Signature".

Comment: Lovely; with RSA 9.1 ... there is no "Show Signature" any more.

Comment: But you can right click on a class instead of a diagram, and then you have it. But only for this class.